# Azure AD B2C - Change Domain

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When you create a B2C tenant and prompted to provide a temporary .onmicrosoft.com domain, the tooltip says that this can be changed later on to a domain our organization currently uses.

[image]

How do we go about accomplishing this and changing the domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, in feedback it is still a work in progress :\ https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains

Comment: @juunas isn't that just for the urls? We want our local accounts to have a custom domain e.g. juuna@xyz.com.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Add your custom domain to Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain).

After the custom domain is added, you may add a local account with it.

Comment: This is the AD part, but does that also work for the local accounts in the B2C?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=applications):

"Can I use my own URLs on my sign-up and sign-in pages that are served by Azure AD B2C? For instance, can I change the URL from contoso.b2clogin.com to login.contoso.com?

Not currently. This feature is on our roadmap. Verifying your domain in the Domains tab in the Azure portal does not accomplish this goal. However, with b2clogin.com, we offer a neutral top-level domain, and thus the external appearance can be implemented without the mention of Microsoft".